# Too slow shortest path algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, path-finding

I am solving one problem with shortest path algorithm, but it is too slow, the problem is that I have N points and these can be connected only if the distance between them is smaller or equal than the D, I have start index and finish("ciel" in code) index and have to return the shortest path in double format. Firstly I thought that the sqrt is too slow, but when I changed it, it was still too slow. I am backtracking the distance and using sqrt just there for better speed, but it is too slow. I have used priortity queue. For more information, the input consists of the X and Y of the points , D maximal distance to make edge, start index and finish index. There can be max 1000 points.

Here is my code http://pastebin.com/pQS29Vw9 Is there any option how to make it faster please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 1001;
const int INF = 1e9;

std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > edges[MAX]; // hrany a vzdialenosti medzi bodmi a hranami
int N; // pocet vrcholov
int start, ciel; // start a ciel index

double dijkstra() {
        int vis[N]; // pocet navstiveni daneho bodu
        int prevNodes[N][2];
        for(int i=0;i < N;i++)
        prevNodes[i][1] = INF;

        std::priority_queue< std::pair<int, int> > heap; // halda
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) vis[i] = 0;
        heap.push(pair<int, int>(0, start));
        while(!heap.empty())
    {
                pair<int, int> min = heap.top(); // vybratie dalsieho
                heap.pop(); // vyhodenie pozreteho
                min.first *= -1.0; // kvoli spravnemu fungovaniu priority
                int v = min.second; // len pre oko

                vis[v]++;
                if (v == ciel && vis[v] == 1)
        {
            double d = 0.0;

            int prevIndex = ciel, nextIndex = prevNodes[ciel][0];

            while(1)
            {

                for(int j=0;j < edges[nextIndex].size();j++)
                    if(edges[nextIndex][j].first == prevIndex)
                    {

                        d += sqrt(double( edges[nextIndex][j].second ));
                        break;
                    }

                prevIndex = nextIndex; // posunutie
                if(nextIndex == start) // ak sme uz na zaciatku
                    break;
                else
                    nextIndex = prevNodes[nextIndex][0];// posun dalej
            }
                        return d; // najkratsia cesta
        }

                for (int i = 0; i < (int) edges[v].size(); i++)
        {
                        if (vis[edges[v][i].first] < 1)
            {
                if(prevNodes[edges[v][i].first][1] > min.first + edges[v][i].second)
                {
                    prevNodes[edges[v][i].first][0] = min.second;

                    prevNodes[edges[v][i].first][1] = min.first + edges[v][i].second;
                }
                                heap.push(pair<int, int>(-(min.first + edges[v][i].second), edges[v][i].first));
            }
                }
        }
        return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int X;
    scanf("%d",&X);
    double answers[X];
    for(int i=0;i < X;i++)
    {
        int D, sIndex, eIndex; // N je globalne
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &D); // N
        int DD = D * D;
        for(int j=0;j < N;j++)
            edges[j].clear();

        int V[N][2]; // N
        int x, y;
        for(int k=0;k < N;k++) // N
        {
            scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
            V[k][0] = x;
            V[k][1] = y;
        }

        for(int a=0;a < N;a++)
            for(int b=0;b < N;b++)
            {

                int v = (((V[a][0] - V[b][0]) * (V[a][0] - V[b][0]) +
                                (V[a][1] - V[b][1]) * (V[a][1] - V[b][1])));
                if(v > DD)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    edges[a].push_back(pair<int, int>(b, v));
                    edges[b].push_back(pair<int, int>(a, v));
                }
            }

        scanf("%d %d", &start, &ciel);
        start--;
        ciel--;
        double dijLen = dijkstra();
        if(dijLen < 0)
            answers[i] = -1;
        else
            answers[i] = dijLen;
    }
    for(int i=0;i < X;i++)
        if(answers[i] < 0)
            printf("Plan B\n");
        else
            printf("%.2f\n", answers[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `sqrt`, a constant function, is largely irrelevant to the performance the algorithm as N grows. What does a *graph* of the execution times for various N look like? Does it fit the expected bounds?

Comment: I cannot find out the bounds so I cannot check anything at all.

Comment: @user1295618 Well, look at the graph of the performance - does it look like it is scaling in a favorable fashion? That is, how does it run for N=10, N=100, N=1000? Are they all "too slow"? Does it just become too slow with a larger N? If so, by what factor? Is it a constant (just-needs-to-be-wall-clock-faster) factor?

Comment: Profile, then edit your question with both the code and the profile results.

Comment: Do you run your code with debug info enabled? Choose another configuration (release configuration) with debug info disabled and try again.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake, it crashes due to memory, bad_alloc, think the edges are the problem, or the priority queue.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41351

Comment: Yes, because Drew B. suggested to ask there, so should I delete this one?

Comment: Can you use a toll like `valgrind` to check for "crashes due to memory"?

Comment: It is not necessary, it is caused by heap because it has more than 67 000 000 items at the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three possible algorithmic improvements to consider:

### Improvement to search

Djikstra's algorithm will explore all points within S of the start node, where S is the shortest distance between the start and the end.

If you use an [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) (e.g. with a heuristic of the Euclidean distance to the goal) then you should find that many fewer points need to be explored.

### Improvement to edge construction

Depending on how the points are distributed, you may find it better to find the edges within a distance D by:

1. Imagine a grid of side length D being overlaid on the plane
2. Add each point into a bucket corresponding to which grid square it belongs to
3. When you need to find the neighbours of a point, you only need to test points in the neighbouring buckets instead of every point.

### Improvement to preprocessing

Depending on the distribution of the points, you may well find that it is more efficient to only construct the valid edges when you reach a vertex, rather than precalculating all edges.

This potentially saves a lot of time if the start and destination are close.

Comment: I modified the code following the tips from cross question in codereview, so now I am checking the edge in dijkstra and the points are sorted by the X coordinate so I can end the loop if two points are > D far. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/0WiuVCNM But, the tester says it gives wrong answer, but on the two test inputs it runs fine, so can you check the logic of the code?

Comment: @user1295618 Try moving the sqrt back into the dist function.  At the moment you are computing the shortest path based on the square of the distance which may not always give the same answer.

Comment: I tried the A* way because it was crashing due to heap overflow. Here it is http://pastebin.com/sNf1w55c , I am waiting response from judge because it cannot get compiled on their compiler.

Comment: I fixed it, but now I am getting wrong answer again, can somebody check the code logic please?